# How do I use aggregates in grouped marks?

Tags: powerbi, vega, deneb

I'm trying to use the min and max aggregates of a quantitative column (Total bombers) grouped by another column (Country) in a rule mark of my visual. I want the rule y property to start at the minimum value of Total bombers and the rule y2 property to end at the maximum value of total bombers, but I can't seem to find the right syntax for the min and max aggregates of the rule mark. I can get the result I'm looking for by not grouping the marks but I would like to implement it for grouped marks so I can re-use it more easily.

Spec for grouped version I'm trying to use min and max aggregates in:
https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykSArJQBWENgDsQAGhAATONABONHJnaT0AQQAETJBBpRtAGxri422EkWZtcAB5IEOY3ErSQAdxqz6aAQAMATLwNGRYaABMQTI4SLKyZmT+MgZk4kjGEGgA2gC6MrJImCioOaAZCHBoIExsCExwitkyDIrGNVi4+ES0EJjUdIxMDBBNUBKYcOIDEwgkssRsbIryigQCTADMAQCcuwDssgAcBwHHCUgHx1tMTJFMuwKykXC7cABmWwAsBIpIngIACF6o1FABSSICaIAcSQOEoUAgxA8HxWyEwaFAmAAnjhqugkSjYtYxliQAAVNglYy6UFNbLocQMBpNDwATTg1hqzNZihAAF8BTJMP9xBA0YoELlsXiCSBJQgGMYUDJ9DUilMPA4cPz0GoqgAKTVwA1wY3FFmUTnWKTaACMdvtAEpnYKpLL8TUPjRjFN+TIdXq5JaENauYptAAeAC8Dt2xwCgryAoKIGgmQUMpAlXl9g8uK9+poVQ8YrI8u8vhgHlk9SQZnJmtKtXpzVRNDgxlkGuK1SFHpzTnlOILcpqpnM3Jk5floXCmJk4kMBNFDDgMgAXk02Gg1xu5PXG6hQM2anU+S0FZ3uzUqTS6ZfBcKKsOahNjCsx0WQCtEhkOhnJBxArd8+zIFZR0KI8NFPYoWwvMErx9Lse3QABhNgGBmRRRyFNMkHsLMylAFZOxmc9qUweoPAzVwanzF9f2UaZMXQVwPkXdMoEzGo8LTZBFAAa0ZcoQELeUyEULCcFRaTpRPBUkCgU1yVzGoxhYq8z3QRCGQ8KSZKYUcMKwnC8OFEBBJE7N5CUFQ1AkGoABkzAsSU7CWYwGEc8RtDYD5tGoh89OaXQcUsMzRSg8Tx3Yty5JoxSdPTJpO2ySzpgmeRyVYtlFPzRS6LzDtUN7LVLJM0Bir40rb3Qe9MkfJD3XTUU2CEglqp4+jCTYT8A2vMrTOw6LWv6aTOvQ+FyWITJ1xqaTsJ7SyJo6uAAHUfD8RS5u8gktlW9rOoAeTiKA6CqkA9oW1AAkoAQhQHU8FCgZRVHUGoAAU2DMTAIG0Dzgqa0KAeMyLRtw795QgHEGn6xKFLgkoNLSrNMvEbKupAPK9VAQrut49B8xkFD6pDCqZCumr0Bism0MpakQbbDLUhobdZvmglAksn1jA6IqevlD8v1Jm8GcwyG8NSY7Nu2mtdq5qIAiOybsZu+VTAXCAhJxJh9ufVocBNck+eMM7lMuzmDdQe1VfWi2Ltxa3bpVyyYDYUg8batXHatxWbbtp7Bzst6HM+9AACVlQZXRTU8OBpgh8ygqZ2lQu0XkWpFOKQEUGPEabeDUa01qsrYHLFIYY2+3JAnuKJkASaG8mTcq8kaZAOnxbvNPmv0yrIhdglohVmW1eHicwiwHW9YN+3Oq26tJ9QQ7x4d87-dADW0Hux6npTFMgA

Spec for non-grouped version that achieves what I want to do:
https://vega.github.io/editor/#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-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-vQVKOti9A-ymQDgMMntUlFNgQbgGt4XJJC2xqHMGHEatef6HNFYAdR8PwybVgktl1+XFYAeTiKA6H50AzbQAJKAEIUEohwSKJE9AAAU2DMTAIG0RGsZxqKRQmkAIBxBoRtREnQu21r+t56ZaYJUAGb1UBmdAVnXo5g7R0MqnHZjwX5RFzmaglgCgJAhzdZoSrVdbAlAl5n1jA6AWXuG0aA3LEuQDrLXjqpvWFbgI2-Pb5CCWiS39azkBna+sIsAgEGcSYReBtaHAxzJnvjFtpB7dxBf1dQe0V5ni+r4rjeAgSjBb0ZgurbgJ+HZvgk98PaJXkN7aG1F4ahxWEjEaDBUboyAree8EdjxuRqATROj0yYtXQLtXG6caZsDpmTHO5J86VwHiAdmI8xbc3LuSQuwt9q0JvHeU0mNnwiQforZWOAAEa3rDrOWq854mydh3NAFthGPztv-U2EjUCu3dsAr2ZEhKUX9oHBCUDIysOQXgyOaV5Sx3jrNBUSdsEp1wZTAhmd6YzC-lQhhVci40K5mOXmFdGF82YVzPR7C-xcNSK3NeG8u4c17s4yhEwh6+MOhPRsU8f6iP8vIg+qBl7SMVvwzeBUd57wPu-PMJ9QBnz-tfNJt975ZN-rIip4j0lv15jAT+ucY4-3KS-BRQDPZGI1sqQm5isFbRKKnPatiiFr1IUzKJQsnHF1oR4mQXiXFMIWX4pBATOGSE8ZEWZ1c4ni2fJLRuMsp4hJyeE8skT+5zJiWNdZ8SGwnRqSky53DQkKIylvYOu997qyKcfMup9fTnzqV09J1T2mr06Tk12FtmmtIYR08FOSenWSAA

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're trying to do isn't logically possible. You have faceted on country. That means each country gets a line (working), a symbol (working) but how would it get a rule where the start point is one country and the end point is the other. One group does not know anything about the other group so you couldn't have a rule spanning the two countries.

If you want to keep your facet, you can do the following:

[image]

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v5.json",
  "description": "A basic line chart example.",
  "width": 500,
  "height": 200,
  "padding": 5,
  "signals": [],
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "bombers",
      "url": "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/vdvoorder/5b30997d8708dda783bb2b95d2e9ef34/raw/Bomber%2520Gap.csv",
      "format": {
        "type": "csv",
        "parse": {"Total bombers": "number", "Year": "number"}
      },
      "transform": [
        {
          "type": "formula",
          "as": "date",
          "expr": "time(datetime(datum.Year, 1, 1))"
        },
        {"type": "filter", "expr": "datum.Year <= 1980"}
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "bombers2",
      "source": "bombers",
      "transform": [
        {
          "type": "pivot",
          "field": "Country",
          "value": "Total bombers",
          "groupby": ["date"]
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "scales": [
    {
      "name": "x",
      "type": "time",
      "range": "width",
      "domain": {"data": "bombers", "field": "date"}
    },
    {
      "name": "y",
      "type": "linear",
      "range": "height",
      "nice": true,
      "zero": true,
      "domain": {"data": "bombers", "field": "Total bombers"}
    },
    {
      "name": "color",
      "type": "ordinal",
      "range": "category",
      "domain": {"data": "bombers", "field": "Country"}
    }
  ],
  "axes": [
    {"orient": "bottom", "scale": "x"},
    {"orient": "left", "scale": "y"}
  ],
  "marks": [
    {
      "type": "group",
      "from": {
        "facet": {"name": "series", "data": "bombers", "groupby": "Country"}
      },
      "marks": [
        {
          "description": "Line for evolution of total bombers by country",
          "type": "line",
          "from": {"data": "series"},
          "encode": {
            "enter": {
              "x": {"scale": "x", "field": "date"},
              "y": {"scale": "y", "field": "Total bombers"},
              "stroke": {"scale": "color", "field": "Country"},
              "strokeCap": {"value": "round"},
              "strokeWidth": {"value": 3},
              "strokeOpacity": {"value": 0.5}
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "description": "Points for total bombers by country",
          "type": "symbol",
          "from": {"data": "series"},
          "encode": {
            "enter": {
              "x": {"scale": "x", "field": "date"},
              "y": {"scale": "y", "field": "Total bombers"},
              "size": {"value": 50},
              "fill": {"scale": "color", "field": "Country"},
              "strokeWidth": {"value": 20},
              "stroke": {"value": "lightskyblue"}
            },
            "update": {
              "fillOpacity": {"value": 1},
              "strokeOpacity": {"value": 0}
            },
            "hover": {"strokeOpacity": {"value": 1}}
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "description": "Rulers between country total bomber numbers",
      "type": "rule",
      "from": {"data": "bombers2"},
      "encode": {
        "update": {
          "x": {"scale": "x", "field": "date"},
          "y": {"scale": "y", "field": "Soviet Union"},
          "y2": {"scale": "y", "field": "United States"},
          "stroke": {"value": "lightskyblue"},
          "strokeWidth": {"value": 3},
          "strokeOpacity": {"value": 0.5}
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: You're right, David. What I tried to do didn't make sense so I indeed went with a pivoted version with separate marks for the countries and just got rid of the facet. Thank you very much for your swift assistance!